# Get silverlight list item with coded ui testmethod

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have a very simple silverligt page which contains this listbox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding itemList}" x:Name="list">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="datatemplate" >
            <Grid Name="grid" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="grid" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Txt}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{Binding Id}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want my Coded UI test to select one of this list item and click on it, but i don't know how to search for itemlists.
I tried everything but i cannot figure out how to get it.

here is my simple testmethod

```
public void ClickOnItem()
{

    SilverlightList list = new SilverlightList(this.UISilverlightApplicatiWindow.UISilverlightApplicatiDocument.UISilverlightControlHoPane.UIItemCustom.UIMainPageMainPage.UIListList);
    list.SearchProperties.Add(SilverlightList.PropertyNames.AutomationId, "list");

    SilverlightListItem item = new SilverlightListItem(list);

    item.SearchProperties.Add(SilverlightListItem.PropertyNames.AutomationId, "3");
    Mouse.Click(item);
}
```

(where "3" is the third element in the list, ofc)

what have i to search for?
do i need additional xaml tags?

Answer (score 0):

I`m not really sure if this is what you want but:

Once you have the Framework element you can access the items using the "Items" property itself.
Example

```
var item = list.Items[index]
```

or using Linq

```
var item = list.Items.First(c => c.Id == 3);
```

Once you have the item you can select it with SelectedItem property as follow:

```
list.SelectedItem = item;
```

or depending on the case

```
list.SelectedValue = item;
```

To fire the click event you can simply call it giving null parameters as

```
list.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(null)
```

Which means you want to fire it with no parameters.

Please refer to the following link as a source
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28VS.95%29.aspx